# Conversion from UTF-8 encoded string to bytes and vice versa in C++

Tags: c++, utf-8, c++14

In C#, we have following functions to convert a string to a UTF-8 encoded sequence of bytes and vice-versa:

1. `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Byte[])`
2. `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Char[])` / `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(String)`

I am trying to achieve the same thing in C++, as follows:

```cpp
std::string GetStringFromBytes(std::vector<uint8_t> bytes){
    std::string str(bytes.begin(), bytes.end());
    return str;
}

std::vector<uint8_t> GetBytesFromString(const std::string& str){
    std::vector<uint8_t> bytes(str.begin(), str.end());
    return bytes;
}
```

Is this approach correct? I'm assuming that the string that I'm converting is already in UTF-8 format.

Comment: `Is this approach correct?` - have you tried it and looked at the result?

Comment: What does "correct" mean?

Comment: `std::string` already has the bytes, you don't have to copy them, just use them. You are hardly converting anything, you are copying.

Answer (score 4):

C# `string` uses UTF-16, and thus requires a *charset conversion* to/from UTF-8.

C++ `std::string` does not use UTF-16 (`std::u16string` does). So, if you have a UTF-8 encoded `std::string`, you already have the raw bytes for it, just copy them as-is. The code you have shown is doing exactly that, and is fine for UTF-8 strings. Otherwise, if you have/need `std::string` encoded in some other charset, you will need a *charset conversion* to/from UTF-8. There are 3rd party Unicode libraries that can handle that, such as libiconv, ICU, etc.